# HTML5 Canvas - Why the canvas axis are affected by transformations?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

There is something that i dont understand about the HTML5 canvas system. Lets say that i have a circle that is centered at (5,5), and i want to scale it by 2, so its center will not move. Ok, so my intuition says to do the following:

1. Move the circle back to (0,0) by `translate(-5,-5)`.
2. Scale it by 2, by applying `scale(2,2)`.
3. Move it back to (5,5), by applying `translate(5, 5)`.

But it won't work, because the canvas was implemented such that translation and scaling will be applied on the canvas axis, and not on the points themselves (for example, translate will only move the origin, and not the circle's center). Am i right?

But why is that? why the transformations just don't apply directly on the points, so everything  will be always relative to (0,0) ? Isn't it the standard way to implement such systems?

am i missing something?

**EDIT:**

Well, i guess that what i missed is that transformations are performed in reverse order, as mentioned [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#transformations). But i still don't get why is that... why not in the original order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transformations do **not** apply to the canvas axis as you believe, but actually to the points. Transformations for the HTML5 2D rendering context are governed by a transformation matrix. The transformation matrix for the *current drawing state* is applied when creating current default path and when painting shapes, images and `Path` objects.

This is what the transformation matrix looks like:

```
[a c tx]
[b d ty]
[0 0  1]
```

where,

**a**  -  x scale, 
**c**  -  x skew, 
**tx** -  x translate

**b**  -  y skew, 
**d**  -  y scale, 
**ty** -  y translate

Let's say you try to paint a pixel at the point `(x, y)`. Here's how the transformation will be applied to it:

```
[sx]   [a c tx] [x]
[sy] = [b d ty]*[y]
[ 1]   [0 0  1] [1]

=>
[sx]   [a*x + c*y + tx]
[sy] = [b*x + d*y + ty]
[ 1]   [ 0  +  0  +  1]
```

`(sx, sy)` are the co-ordinates on the **output bitmap** where the pixel will actually be painted. With the identity matrix (`a = 1, c = 0, tx = 0, b = 0, d = 1, ty = 0`), `(sx, sy)` will be the same as `(x, y)`, as is the default case.

Now, the fact that the transformation matrix for the canvas uses column vectors for co-ordinates gives us the reason why transformations seem to apply in the reverse order.

Let's take your example. You change the transformation matrix with the following statements:

```
translate(-5, -5);
scale(2, 2);
translate(5, 5);
```

Let's run through how these statements affect the transformation matrix:

```
//default
[1 0 0]
[0 1 0]
[0 0 1]

->translate(-5, -5)
[1 0 0]   [1 0 -5]
[0 1 0] * [0 1 -5]
[0 0 1]   [0 0  1]
=>
[1 0 -5]
[0 1 -5]           //Using MI = IM = M, I is Identity Matrix
[0 0  1]

->scale(2, 2)
[1 0 -5]   [2 0 0]
[0 1 -5] * [0 2 0]
[0 0  1]   [0 0 1]
=>
[(1*2 + 0*0 + -5*0) (1*0 + 0*2 + -5*0) (1*0 + 0*0 + -5*1)]
[(0*2 + 1*0 + -5*0) (0*0 + 1*2 + -5*0) (0*0 + 1*0 + -5*1)]
[(0*2 + 0*0 +  1*0) (0*0 + 0*2 +  1*0) (0*0 + 0*0 +  1*1)]
=>
[2 0 -5]
[0 2 -5]
[0 0  1]

->translate(5, 5)
[2 0 -5]   [1 0 5]
[0 2 -5] * [0 1 5]
[0 0  1]   [0 0 1]
=>
[(2*1 + 0*0 + -5*0) (2*0 + 0*1 + -5*0) (2*5 + 0*5 + -5*1)]
[(0*1 + 2*0 + -5*0) (0*0 + 2*1 + -5*0) (0*5 + 2*5 + -5*1)]
[(0*1 + 0*0 +  1*0) (0*0 + 0*1 +  1*0) (0*5 + 0*5 +  1*1)]
=>
[2 0 5]
[0 2 5] 
[0 0 1]
```

Which means, for a point `(x, y)`, corresponding `(sx, sy)` is

```
[sx]   [2*x + 5]   [2*x + 0*y + 5] 
[sy] = [2*y + 5] = [0*x + 2*y + 5] 
[ 1]   [   1   ]   [0*x + 0*y + 1]
```

So, if `(5, 5)` was the center you did not want scale to affect, with the current code it will be drawn at `(15, 15)`.

Note that I first multiplied all the three matrices to create the new transformation matrix, which might not make it very clear why transformations seem to be applied in reverse. But, if **T1** represents first translate statement, **S** the scale statement and **T2** the second translate statement, while **X** represents the column vector for the point to be transformed, it's easy to see

```
T = I*T1*S*T2 
=>
T = T1*S*T2
```

Then, if **C** represents the column vector for `(sx, sy)`,

```
C = T*X
=>
C = T1*S*T2*X
=>
C = T1*S*X'      //X' is X transformed by T2
=>
C = T1*X''       //X'' is X' transformed by S
=>
C = X'''         //X''' is X'' transformed by T1

or
    [(x+5)*2 - 5]
C = [(y+5)*2 - 5] = X''' 
    [     1     ]
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks. So, i don't understand why most of the tutorials/books teach the readers that the transformations change the coordinate system. I mean, maybe its possible to explain it like that, but i think it's much more intuitive to look at transformations as what they really do - apply to each point.

Answer (score 2):

This is where `.save` and `.restore` come into play.

Transformations aren't done on objects.
Transformations are done on the coordinate-space.

Think about this for a second:
Canvas is an immediate-mode drawing context.
Once you put an object down, it's stuck there for eternity, as numbers inside of a huge array.

So you can't make a square and then render it and afterwards rescale it and move it, et cetera, unless you, yourself are keeping track of virtual "objects" in a scene-graph you made yourself, where you're doing your own erasing and updating of the rastered image, as needed.

So if you're painting a picture, and you want to scale a particular character, you scale the coordinates, position and draw all of your pieces at that scale and origin, and then reset your transforms, in the reverse order.

Otherwise, this happens:

```
scale(2) => translate(5,5) =>
scale(0.5) => translate(-5, -5)
```

moves you 10 right, 10 down, and then 5 left and 5 up.

Comment: Well, the transformations do apply to the objects themselves. It looks like they are done on the coordinate space because they are applied in reverse order to how to declared them, and that's what is weird to me, because i'm used that the transformations are applied on the objects themselves.

Comment: If you want to think of your transformation as it works on the points themselves, then you have to specify it in a reverse order to the canvas.

Comment: ...yes.  Because transforms are applied to the coordinate-space.  Not to the object.  Coordinate-space and Canvas-view-space aren't even the same thing.  If you scale by 2, and then move (5, 5), you're at Canvas' (10, 10).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your intuition is correct...

Transforms are always done in order-received ;)

Congratulations for going to the whatWG source to get info--not many people are brave enough to do that!

What the whatWG is saying is that if you execute some transforms (say translate then scale) and then do a drawing...then to get back to your original un-transformed state you must undo the transforms in reverse order (unscale then untranslate).

**[ additional Illustration ]**

This is an illustration of un-transforming:

1. Draw a blue reference dot at [50,50]
2. Do some transforms  // translate(100,100), scale(2,2)
3. Draw a rectangle at the transformed coordinates
4. Undo the tranforms  // scale(0.5, 0.5), translate(-100,-100)
5. Draw a red reference dot at [50,50]

*The dots will align **only if** we have exactly un-translated !*

[image]

Mission Accomplished!

Notice we had to undo the transforms in reverse order from their creation.

Again, **UNDO** in reverse order.

And since we originally scaled up by 2X, we need to unscale by 0.5.

And since we originally translated(moved) by 100,100 we need to untranslate -100,-100

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/VGLRu/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    drawReferenceDot(15,"blue");

    ctx.beginPath();
    // transform
    ctx.translate(100,100);
    ctx.scale(2,2);

    // draw
    ctx.rect(0,0,25,25);
    ctx.fill();

    // un-transform (in exactly reverse order)
    // first un-scale -- using 0.5,0.5
    // then un-transform -- using -100,-100
    ctx.scale(0.5,0.5);
    ctx.translate(-100,-100);

    // draw a second reference dot
    // if we've correctly "untransformed" the dots should align
    drawReferenceDot(8,"red");


    function drawReferenceDot(radius,color){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle=color;
        ctx.arc(50,50,radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        ctx.fill();
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure that they are performed in the order they received? here is an example given by whatWG - `For instance, if a scale transformation that doubles the width is applied to the canvas, followed by a rotation transformation that rotates drawing operations by a quarter turn, and a rectangle twice as wide as it is tall is then drawn on the canvas, the actual result will be a square.`.

Comment: And for example, what i written in my post will work, if i will really perform the steps in reverse order. i mean, first `translate(5,5)`, then `scale(2,2)` and finally `translate(-5,-5)`. So it means that they are performed in reverse order.

Comment: See my edited answer for an illustration of un-transforming :)

Comment: Hi man, I really appreciate your effort. I understand the concept of un-transforming, but still, i don't think that that's what whatWG meant by `The transformations must be performed in reverse order.`. They really meant that the transformation will be applied in the reverse order to each point, and that's what really happening. I just don't get why it is like that... maybe it is like that because they want to give you the feel that you don't alter the points themselves, but you alter the canvas instead.

Comment: Yes, that's how it will look like if you will write transformation sequence that was meant to work on the points themselves. Because the canvas will apply the sequence in reverse order, it will look like they were applied to the coordinate space.